# Why Wireshark only show one-way of the VirtualBox Host-Only network communication?

Tags: tcp, virtualbox, wireshark

I am using the Virtual Box. The virtual machine is using the Host Only Network since this is the only way for Wireshark to monitor the packets sent from a VM.

[image]

Below is my virtual/host machine topology.

the Guest OS is visiting some website host on the Host OS.

[image]

Below is what I captured with Wireshark:

[image]

My question is:

Why there are only `VM -> Host` packets?

Where are the `Host -> VM` packets?

Comment: I am eager to know the answer as well

Comment: I also have same problem, even with the newest version of both wireshark and virtualbox. Do you already find solution for this?

Comment: Did you ever solve this?

Comment: @baruch not yet

Comment: @smwikipedia same Issue, please update in case you get to know something

Comment: I have the same problem

Comment: Show your interfaces list and which one you are sniffing on